# Как переставить элементы массива?

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

Последовательность чисел от `0` до `N-1` (`N >= 2` - целое) случайным образом перемешали, получив массив `A` длины `N`. Необходимо изменить массив так, чтобы по окончании работы новый элемент `A[i]` содержал значение, равное `A[A[i]]` в старом массиве, для всех `i` от `0` до `N-1`, **используя O(1) дополнительной памяти**.

Например, на входе `A = {1, 2, 7, 0, 9, 3, 6, 8, 5, 4}`.

Тогда на выходе `A = {2, 7, 8, 1, 4, 0, 6, 5, 3, 9}`.

Я пробовал вот так:

```
size_t pos_1 = 0, pos_2 = A[0], assigned = 0;

while (assigned != A.size() - 1 && pos_2 != 0) {
    std::swap(A[pos_1], A[pos_2]);
    std::swap(pos_1, pos_2);
    pos_2 = A[pos_2];
    ++assigned;
}
```

Но, если мы приходим снова к 0-му элементу, а ещё не всё обменялось, то ответ неверный. Также пробовал квадратное решение:

```
size_t pos = 0, assigned = 0;
int tmp = A[A[pos]];

while (assigned != A.size()) {
    std::swap(A[pos], tmp);
    pos = std::find(A.cbegin(), A.cend(), pos) - A.cbegin();
    ++assigned;
}
```

Но тогда на каком-то этапе возникает 2 одинаковых числа в массиве и `std::find` находит первое из них, что, вообще говоря, неверно.

Comment: Не понял условие `A[i] = A[A[i]]`. Допустим, `i=3`. В вашем примере `A[3]=1`, `A[A[3]]=7`. Никак не равны.

Comment: @maestro имеется в виду, для исходного массива элемент `A[3]=0` стал равен `A[A[3]=0]=1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На самом деле эта задача имеет нетривиальное, но очень простое после вникания в него решение :)

1. К каждому `A[i]` нужно прибавить `(A[A[i]]%N)*N`
2. Каждое `A[i]` нужно поделить на `N`...

Все!

```
int A[10] = {1, 2, 7, 0, 9, 3, 6, 8, 5, 4};

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        A[i] += (A[A[i]]%10)*10;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        A[i] /= 10;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        printf("%d  ",A[i]);

    puts("");
}
```

Comment: Для достаточно больших массивов тут есть опасность не поместиться в `int`.

Comment: @Yaant Есть - при N, грубо говоря, большем чем максимально представимое значение пополам. В каком-то смысле мы используем память O(N) - просто все равно выделенную, только не использованную :) Увы, но другого решения у меня нет... Но с интересом бы ознакомился с таковым.

Comment: Мне кажется, можно что-то придумать со сменой знака, только не соображу, что именно. :)

Comment: @Yaant то же самое возражение: использование лишнего бита знака...

Comment: А тут уже надо определиться, идет ли речь о чистом алгоритме, без каких-либо ограничений на величину `N`, хоть до числа Грэма и более (в этом случае, тут действительно будет использоваться `O(N)` дополнительной памяти), или о его практической реализации на существующих языках программирования и компьютерах. :)

Comment: При всем уважении, не понял смысла нахождения остатка: если A < 10, то A%10 ==A. Все А < 10 по условию.

Comment: Игра в пятнашки, вот вам и весь алгоритм.

Comment: @0andriy Ну, тогда расставьте этим алгоритмом по местам ряд 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,13... :)

Comment: @BuilderC Дело в том, что после того, как вы выполните первые увеличения, значения выходят за диапазон [0,N-1]...